# android:inputType does not function after adding caligraphy

Tags: android, calligraphy

After adding calligraphy to applied the font, password become blurred and cannot be viewed. I have applied  `android:fontFamily="sans-serif"` but still it is still the same. Calligraphy that i am using is
 `implementation uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0`, while my `sdkVersion` is 21, library is `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1`

**signin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_borenos"
tools:context="com.example.liew.idelivery.SignIn">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPhone"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:text="0128688032"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
        app:met_maxCharacters="12"
        app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
        app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
        />

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:text="chau95"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
        app:met_maxCharacters="12"
        app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"

        />

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="2">

       <com.rey.material.widget.CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/ckbRemember"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Remember me"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           app:cbd_strokeColor="@android:color/white"
           app:cbd_tickColor="@android:color/black"
           style="@style/Material.Drawable.CheckBox"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:id="@+id/txtForgotPwd"
           android:text="@string/forgot_pwd"/>

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
    android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:fButtonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
    app:cornerRadius="4dp"
    app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
    app:shadowEnabled="true"
    app:shadowHeight="5dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**SignIn.java**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;
import com.rey.material.widget.CheckBox;
import io.paperdb.Paper;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edtPhone,edtPassword;
Button btnSignIn;
CheckBox ckbRemember;
TextView txtForgotPwd;

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference table_user;

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //add calligraphy
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/restaurant_font.otf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

    edtPhone = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
    edtPassword = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
    ckbRemember = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ckbRemember);
    txtForgotPwd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtForgotPwd);

    //Init paper
    Paper.init(this);

    //Init firebase

    database =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    table_user = database.getReference("User");

    txtForgotPwd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showForgotPwdDialog();
        }
    });

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (Common.isConnectedToInternet(getBaseContext())) {

                //save user & password
                if(ckbRemember.isChecked()){
                    Paper.book().write(Common.USER_KEY, edtPhone.getText().toString());
                    Paper.book().write(Common.PWD_KEY, edtPassword.getText().toString());
                }

                final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
                mDialog.setMessage("Please waiting...");
                mDialog.show();

                table_user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        //check if user not exist in database

                        if (dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).exists()) {


                            //Get user information

                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            User user = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);

                            // set phone
                            user.setPhone(edtPhone.getText().toString());
                            if (user.getpassword().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {

                                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(SignIn.this, Home.class);
                                Common.currentUser = user;
                                startActivity(homeIntent);
                                finish();

                                table_user.removeEventListener(this);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Wrong Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "User not exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Please check your internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void showForgotPwdDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Forgot Password");
    builder.setMessage("Enter your secure code");

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View forgot_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forgot_password_layout, null);

    builder.setView(forgot_view);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_security_black_24dp);

    final MaterialEditText edtPhone = (MaterialEditText)forgot_view.findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
    final MaterialEditText edtSecureCode = (MaterialEditText)forgot_view.findViewById(R.id.edtSecureCode);

    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //check if user still available
            table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString())
                            .getValue(User.class);

                    if (user.getSecureCode().equals(edtSecureCode.getText().toString()))
                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Your password: "
                                +user.getpassword(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Wrong secure code!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  EditTextPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
            InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Thanks man. But i solve with this method   edtPhone.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Nabila.ttf"));